ambobus? (a morphologically peculiar adjective with a peculiar syntax here)
There is a very famous passage in the Aeneid that narrates its hero looking at some pictures of the Trojan War, which he barely escaped from:

Miratur. Videt Iliacas ex ordine pugnas,
Bellaque iam fama totum vulgata per orbem,
Atridas Priamumque et saeuum ambobus Achillem.

This passage is almost completely straightforward, but I am a little bit uncertain about the
use of ambobus above. Since it is an (numeral) adjective, I've searched for some ablative name that would be attached to it, but unsuccessfully. Could anyone figure out what the numeral is doing in this passage?

Ambobus here means "to both [of them]", used as a substantive—there's no noun it attaches to, it stands alone. Who who are "both of them"? In this case, it's Atridas Priamumque: the sons of Atreus on the one hand, and Priam on the other. Achilles is being saevum to both his allies and his enemies, with horrible results for them both.
